# Reading pairs of rows from a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I want it to read rows 0 and 1, 0 for username and 1 for password, and if it doesn't find it it adds 2 to the row number so it read 2 for the username and then 3 for the password and so forth.

My file looks like this:

```
daniel
password
user
password
user
password
etc user
etc password

def PupilLogin():

    print "*********************************"
    print "* Welcome to Spelling Bee Pupil *"
    print "*********************************"
    print "Enter your details below..\n"
    strID = raw_input("Username : ")
    strPassWd = getpass.getpass("Password : ")
    with open('studentsusers.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        username = 0
        password = 1
        for row in spamreader:
            strLoginID = row[username]
            strLoginPasswd = row[password]
            while strLoginID != "":
                if strID == strLoginID and strLoginPasswd == strPassWd:
                    print strID, "Logged In"
                    PupilMenu()
                    strContinue = sys.stdin.readline()
                    return
                else:
                    username += 2
                    password += 2
    #if we get here there is no such login and id
    print "Login ID or password incorrect, press enter to continue"
    strContinue = sys.stdin
```

I think the problem is something to do with the fact I haven't used integers but I actually don't have a clue I think I'm being stupid here to be honest just wishing for any sort of help.

Comment: You show newline delimited input and yet your csv reader is doing comma delimited work.  This problem is really poorly worded.

Comment: Basically, I'm new to Python, and coding in general. I'm stuck on reading pairs of lines to check, if a set of user input data is found there, and if not go to the next pair of rows and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your code expects a comma-delimited csv file that would look something like this:

```
daniel, password
user, password
```

So each row has a username (`row[0]`) and a password (`row[1]`), separated by a comma. You can easily assign these to variables using the form `username, password = row`.

The `for row in spamreader` part of your code iterates through each row, so on the first iteration, `row` equals `["daniel", "password"]`, etc.

I would change your .csv file to fit that format, and then do the relevant part of your code like this:

```
strID = raw_input("Username : ")
strPassWd = getpass.getpass("Password : ")

with open('studentsusers.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in spamreader:
        strLoginID, strLoginPasswd = row

        while strLoginID != "":
            if strID == strLoginID and strLoginPasswd == strPassWd:
                print strID, "Logged In"
                PupilMenu()
                strContinue = sys.stdin.readline()
                return
            else:
                break   # goes on to the next row in spamreader

#if we get here there is no such login and id
print "Login ID or password incorrect, press enter to continue"
strContinue = sys.stdin
```

EDIT: I should mention that it's generally a good idea to release file resources as soon as you don't need them anymore. In this example, you no longer need your csv file once the user is logged in, so I would consider pulling out the `PupilMenu()` call and calling it *after* the file is closed (i.e. after the `with` block). Consider this:

```
strID = raw_input("Username : ")
strPassWd = getpass.getpass("Password : ")

loggedIn = False

with open('studentsusers.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in spamreader:
        strLoginID, strLoginPasswd = row

        while strLoginID != "":
            if strID == strLoginID and strLoginPasswd == strPassWd:
                print strID, "Logged In"
                loggedIn = True
                return
            else:
                break   # goes on to the next row in spamreader

if loggedIn:
    PupilMenu()
    strContinue = sys.stdin.readline()
else:
    print "Login ID or password incorrect, press enter to continue"
    strContinue = sys.stdin
```

EDIT 2: I refactored your code a little bit, just for fun. I think this is a little easier to read/understand:

```
def Welcome():
    print "*********************************"
    print "* Welcome to Spelling Bee Pupil *"
    print "*********************************"
    print "Enter your details below..\n"

    strID = raw_input("Username : ")
    strPassWd = getpass.getpass("Password : ")

    if loggedIn(strID, strPassWd):
        PupilMenu()
        strContinue = sys.stdin.readline()
    else:
        print "Login ID or password incorrect, press enter to continue"
        strContinue = sys.stdin

def loggedIn(user, password)
    with open('studentsusers.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

        for row in spamreader:
            strLoginID, strLoginPasswd = row

            while strLoginID != "":
                if strLoginID == user and strLoginPassWd == password:
                    print user, "Logged In"
                    return True
                else:
                    break
```

Comment: Perfect! thank you so much. I see where I was going wrong now.

Comment: @Danster549 Not a problem! Just for fun, I refactored the structure of your code a little bit. See edit #2 on my answer. Best of luck on your journey in learning Python and programming in general!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have username and password stored on different lines, you can do that.

So, one neat thing about python file input objects, is that you can iterate through the lines automatically! So you don't actaully even need your csv reader:

```
with open('inputfile', 'r') as inputfile:
   for line in inputfile:
       print line
```

This would print every line of the file.

Then, to read pairs of lines, we can use a cool python trick to turn a list into a list of pairs.

```
with open('passwords_file', 'r') as f:
  from itertools import izip
  line_iter = iter(f)
  for username_line, password_line in izip(line_iter, line_iter):
     if strID == username_line.rstrip() and strPassWd == password_line.rstrip():
        print strID, "Logged In"
        PupilMenu()
        strContinue = sys.stdin.readline()
        return
  # If you make it here, the username/password pair wasn't found.
```

(The `rstrip()` is necessary, because otherwise the endlines will be part of the string.)

Finally, you might not want to read linearly through your database every time a user enters his/her password. It might be better to start by reading the username/password combos into a dictionary, then use that dictionary for the log in process! That way, you can have the user try over and over until they get it, much more efficiently.

```
import getpass

def AttemptLogIn(user_to_passwd):
   while True:
     strID = raw_input("Username : ")
     strPassWd = getpass.getpass("Password : ")

     if strID not in user_to_passwd or user_to_passwd[strID] != strPassWd:
        print "Sorry, username or password not found."
     else:
        print strID, "Logged In"
        return

user_to_passwd = {}

with open('passwords_file', 'r') as f:
  line_iter = iter(f)
  from itertools import izip
  for username, password in izip(line_iter, line_iter):
    user_to_passwd[username.rstrip()] = password.rstrip()

AttemptLogIn(user_to_passwd)

PupilMenu()
strContinue = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Comment: Thanks man but I think the comment above suit my purpose better none of the less great answer!